# Convert a date in Shell

Tags: shell, unix, date

This is a hart one, how do I convert a date like

```
12-23-11 13:37
```

In something like(seconds should always be 00)

```
Fri Dec 23 13:18:58 CET 2011
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gnu date 5.97, you can do:

```
$ date -d '11-12-23 13:37'
```

to get what you want, so all you need to do is massage your input.

Since gnu date is not ubiquitous, here's a quick perl script that does what you want:

```
$ echo 12-23-11 13:37 |
    perl -MTime::Local -wnE '
    y/-:/  /;
    @F=split;
    say scalar localtime timelocal( 0, $F[4], $F[3], $F[1], $F[0] - 1,$F[2]);
'
Fri Dec 23 13:37:00 2011
```

(Requires perl 5.10 for -E and say, but should work in older perl using -e and print.)

Comment: Well but my date is MM-DD-YY MM:SS this example only works with YY-MM-DD MM:SS

Comment: Hence the phrase 'massage your input'.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a script for yourself and not something that will have to run in a million different environments, then depending on what version of `date` you have available, you should be able to use it.

Read the man page for your particular version of `date`.  For example, if it's the version documented at http://ss64.com/bash/date.html, you can use `--date` for the input string, etc.

On Mac OS X, use the `-f` option to specify the input format, the `-j` option so that it doesn't try to set the date, and with specifying the output format on the command line.